# Puppet - deep merge lookup default_value with hiera hash returned

Tags: merge, puppet, lookup, hiera

I am trying to deep merge the lookup 'default_value' or 'default_values_hash' with the hash returned from a lookup.  It will not merge and the default_value only appear to take effect if the hiera title isn't found at all.  I cannot set resource defaults here as the values returned are later processed and not actual resource keys yet.

I've tried numerous variations including 'default_value', 'default_values_hash'.  I'm seeking a way to just set a default hash in the manifest and have it deep merge with hiera to create a larger hash.

Manifest:

```
class test (
Hash     $result = lookup('test::my_hash', {merge => 'deep', default_values_hash => {foo => 'bar', this => 'that', him => 'her'}}),
){

notice($result)

}

include test
```

Hiera:

```
---
test::my_hash:
foo:  'nobar'
this: 'then'
```

## desired result (deep merge):

{ foo => 'nobar', this => 'then', him => 'her' }

## actual result (returns hiera hash only):

{ foo => 'nobar', this => 'then' }

UPDATE:

I got it working with the code below.  Still interested if anyone has a better solution.

```
class test (

$stuff = {
foo  => 'bar',
this => 'that',
him  => 'her'
},
Hash     $result = deep_merge($stuff, lookup('test::my_hash')),

){

notice($result)

}
```

Comment: Instead of `lookup( [<NAME>], <OPTIONS HASH> )`, why not use the more common and easier to use usage of `lookup( <NAME>, [<VALUE TYPE>], [<MERGE BEHAVIOR>], [<DEFAULT VALUE>] )`? That could work for you.

Comment: Is the lookup syntax you suggest a newer method, or just the more common?

Comment: I misread the question, so the more common and easier usage would not allow a deep merge with your default value arguments to the `lookup` function. However, most people leverage a `common.yaml` in the lowest level of the hierarchy to provide default values. Utilizing that would enable you to perform a deep merge with default values in your `lookup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is the way `lookup` works. The default value is only used if no other value is found. The [documentation for the default in `lookup`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#lookup.) says

> If present, lookup returns this when it can’t find a normal value. Default values are never merged with found values.

Your version using the `deep_merge` function from `stdlib` appears to be the best solution.

```
class foo {
  $default_foo_attribute = {
    foo  => 'bar',
    this => 'that',
    him  => 'her',
  }

  $attribute = deep_merge($default_foo_attribute,
                          lookup('foo::attribute',
                                 Hash[String, String],
                                 'deep',
                                 {})
  notice($attribute)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon,  looking at my update in the original question (where I use the deep_merge function), could you improve on that or is it appropriate usage?

Comment: No problems! Thanks for the accepted answer. I think the usage is appropriate, yes. I think I'd use variable names to clarify that the defaults are defaults, and I'd think about adding a type, a merge strategy and a default to the lookup. I've added an example to the answer, if that helps.